# How do I take advantage of struct GtkTextViewClass

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

For example I want to use struct GtkTextViewClass's member (function pointer as it appears) `draw_layer ()` which is described as follows:

> draw_layer () The draw_layer vfunc is called before and after the text
>   view is drawing its own text. Applications can override this vfunc in
>   a subclass to draw customized content underneath or above the text. In
>   the GTK_TEXT_VIEW_LAYER_BELOW_TEXT and GTK_TEXT_VIEW_LAYER_ABOVE_TEXT
>   the drawing is done in the buffer coordinate space, but the older
>   (deprecated) layers GTK_TEXT_VIEW_LAYER_BELOW and
>   GTK_TEXT_VIEW_LAYER_ABOVE work in viewport coordinates, which makes
>   them unnecessarily hard to use. Since: 3.14

However, it is very unclear of how to use it as it is referenced in more like a C++ manner. And the internet is severely lacking examples, tutorials, instructions and in fact everything related to this.

---

Should I copy/paste the [implementation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#GtkTextViewClass) in my header file ?
Okay and then.. what ? Can anyone give an example usage of `draw_layer ()` ?

Comment: The function pointers in the class structure are used by subclasses to implement virtual methods and, in some cases, default signal handler implementations. Are you familiar with creating custom GObjects or GtkWidget classes?

Comment: Not at all. This just appears to be the best (not to say the only) way I could do what I want. That is, to draw around text. I succeeded this, but the drawing is being erased when textview must be repainted.